# Is it possible to open Data Grid from auto complete text box in WPF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

Is it possible to open Data Grid from auto complete text box?. Data Grid should be filter on text entered in a text box. I am using WPF MVVM.

Comment: Are you binding the DataGrid? Because i would definitly bind the datagrid filter with the textbox content

Comment: No. I can do Data Grid Binding and filter. But I need Data Grid as auto complete suggestion on Text box. Means when someone enter text on text box it will display data grid with related data

Comment: Which AutoCompleteTextBox are you using?

Comment: I am using WPF toolkit autocompletebox. For the reference you can see here..  http://www.broculos.net/2014/04/wpf-autocompletebox-autocomplete-text.html#.VZVC_Lmqqko

Comment: Maybe you could set a trigger that opens and filters your datagrid on keydown

Comment: @Dharmesh - What have you tried? Also is using DataGrid control must? Can't you display your tabular data with XAML Grid! It's just a matter of formatting ItemTemplate.